# How to pass committers between jobs if only the first job refreshes sources from SVN?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

There is one job which refreshes sources from SVN and builds these sources.
After build this job sends notification about build to committers.
Then this job triggers second job using "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" plugin.
Second job did not refresh from SVN anything. It just run some tools using classes compiled by the first job.
I need to send notification to the committers if second job will be failed.
Is it possible to pass committers from the first job to the second?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible. You may have to combine both jobs into one.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Blame Upstream Committers](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Blame+Upstream+Committers+Plugin) plugin. Currently it works properly only when the Parametrized Build plugin is invoked as a Post-Build Action, not as a build step (due to a bug in the Parameterized Build plugin which is being claimed to have been fixed, but not released, yet).